# Query jsonb Having an Array Using JPA2 Specification

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Have a requirement to query a jsonb column containing an arrays using Jpa Specfication/Predicate
Table Item Table Item with a jsonb column list_val with data ["a","b","c"]

```
Row 1: list_val Column value ["a","b","c"]
Row 2: list_val column value ["c","d","e"]
Row 3: list_val column value ["e","g","h"]
```

Would like to define a jpa specification for postgres with a criteria having a String List:["a","c"] that would result in Row 1 and Row 2 as they have atleast one of elements in my array.
Query with criteria : ["a","x"] should return Row 1
Query with criteria : ["a","d","g"] should return Row 1, Row 2 and Row 3

Comment: select * from mytable where list_val ?& array['a','b'] returns Row 1 but have not figured out how to query this using a Jpa Spec (Also it matches only if both a and b exists in the column

Comment: Any help in actually executing this query on select jsonb_path_exists(list_val,'$ ? (@ == "a") '),* from mytable Would help.